# Graceful way to run subscripts in Python

Tags: python

I have a main script which imports a number of subscripts and runs them. No output is needed to return to the main script.

I'm wondering if there's a better way of running the subscripts. I run the main file with a bat file. If there's an error in any of the subscripts, the script ends with running the full list of subscripts. I tried using a try: except: block loop for each script but it doesn't prevent early exit from the main script.

Is it better to use something like exec or execfile()

```py
from a import b
from c import d

script_list = [a(),b()]

for script in script_list:
    script
```

Comment: Is this your actual script? In that case the last two lines are redundant and can be removed.

Comment: That code doesn't work.

Comment: why not use the try/except in the main program?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure the code "works", but not in the way the OP thought.

Comment: What do a() and b() return? Another function or? Because what you're doing here is filling the list with the output of calls to imported functions and then iterating through the results without doing anything.

Comment: @quamrana Depends on what we mean with "works". If a code crashes, I don't consider it working.

Comment: @KellyBundy: I just assumed that in some cases the code doesn't crash and so it would perform the functions that the OP requires.

Comment: @quamrana Well ok, if the last module contains an infinite loop, then the NameError for `a()` won't get reached and it won't crash, yes.

Comment: I'd expect this script to raise a NameError on trying to call `a()`.  Also agree that iterating over the results of calling the functions is pointless -- you've already called them!

Comment: Yeah, that part doesn't make sense either.

Comment: When you say _the script ends with running the full list of subscripts_ did you mean that the script ends __without__ running the subscripts? Do you want all of them to run? Should they run one at a time or can they all be run at once? You haven't actually stated your problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of what you are asking is that you want to run a number of functions, one after another and ignore any exceptions that they raise. If so this is the code you are looking for:

```py
from a import b
from c import d
from e import f  # I made this one up

script_list = [b, d, f]  # just a list of functions that should be called

for script in script_list:
    try:
        script()    # each function is called here
    except Exception:
        pass        # any exceptions are ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact your code is wrong, as pointed out, you can:

Use the function `sys.exit()`. When called from anywhere in the code, it will terminate the whole program.

Handle the exceptions inside the imported functions and make them  return True on success, False otherwise. (Or 0, 1, or whatever).

As has been suggested, use a try, except block in the main program.